# spark-submit Error: java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.scheduler.mode

Tags: apache-spark, ubuntu-16.04, apache-hudi

I am trying to setup Apache Hudi on an Ubuntu 16.04 server. I cloned the repo https://github.com/apache/incubator-hudi.git and then build it as

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests -DskipITs
```

The build completed successfully.

I then proceeded with testing by following through https://hudi.incubator.apache.org/docker_demo.html

When I try to execute

```
spark-submit --class com.uber.hoodie.utilities.deltastreamer.HoodieDeltaStreamer $HUDI_UTILITIES_BUNDLE --storage-type COPY_ON_WRITE --source-class com.uber.hoodie.utilities.sources.JsonKafkaSource --source-ordering-field ts  --target-base-path /user/hive/warehouse/stock_ticks_cow --target-table stock_ticks_cow --props /var/demo/config/kafka-source.properties --schemaprovider-class com.uber.hoodie.utilities.schema.FilebasedSchemaProvider
```

I get the output

```
...  
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.scheduler.mode  
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$$anonfun$get$1.apply(SparkConf.scala:245)  
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$$anonfun$get$1.apply(SparkConf.scala:245)  
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)  
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.get(SparkConf.scala:245)  
    at com.uber.hoodie.utilities.deltastreamer.HoodieDeltaStreamer.main(HoodieDeltaStreamer.java:286)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)  
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)  
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)  
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)  
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)  
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)  
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)  
...
```

Due to insufficient reputation I could not add incubator-hudi tag to the question.
Thanks for help

Comment: which hudi version are you using? can you try with https://github.com/apache/incubator-hudi/archive/hoodie-0.4.7.zip ?

Comment: @jaimin03
I am using the latest version obtained by cloning the github repo 

I previously tried the version 0.4.7 and this issue did not arise in that version and I successfully executed the first 7 steps in https://hudi.apache.org/docker_demo.html. However, when I tried to execute the Step 8 (https://hudi.apache.org/docker_demo.html#step-8-schedule-and-run-compaction-for-merge-on-read-dataset) , trying to execute 'connect --path /user/hive/warehouse/stock_ticks_mor' resulted in error that there was no such command. So I went for the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved in the updated code

https://github.com/apache/incubator-hudi/issues/767
https://github.com/apache/incubator-hudi/pull/758